# "New Contact" missing from publisher actions

Tags: page-layout, global-actions

I am currently attempting to change the publisher actions available on the "Account" object.

I want to edit the action layout for new tasks, however to do this I have to remove the "mobile smart actions" which contains the default "New Task" and then add in a replacement.

Once I have removed the "mobile smart actions" I have added the individual actions ("new note, new event, etc.) back into the page layout, however I have noticed that "New Contact" does not display when viewing an account in SF1 or desktop.

Does anyone have any ideas why this may be the case? I realise that this is more of an admin question than development, but I figure someone may be able to help.

Comment: Admin questions are legal here. Have no fear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely due to record types on the Contact object.

Mobile Smart Actions display the standard page layout assigned for an object, taking into account record types and user profiles.

Publisher actions are specific to the record type. If you have record types on a standard object, the out-of-box action will be using the Master record type. Unless the profile you're using has access to the Master record type, you won't see the action.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in implementing, but it looks like you're spot on.  It would seem that you can't have access to the "Master" record type if you have access to other record types. In view of this I've created a new account action "Add a contact" and added that in!  Success! Thanks